# SQL dates come back as chr. I cannot cast to date, or create new date columns using dbplyr & SQL Server

Tags: r, sql-server, casting, dbplyr, r-dbi

SQL type of DATE are being returned as characters in my results.   I cannot cast anything to DATE.  Here is a reprex.

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                 Driver = "SQL Server",
                 Server = "*****"
                 Database = "******",
                 user = "******",
                 password = "****",
                 Port = ****)

# Create Test table
dbSendStatement(con, "CREATE table dbo.my_table 
(zipcode int, myDate date, myDateTime datetime, animal varchar(20));")

#Create Test Data
dbSendStatement(con,"insert into my_table (zipcode, myDate, myDateTime, animal)
 values (90210, '2010-01-01', GETDATE(), 'cat')")

tbl(con, "my_table") %>% 
  mutate(castDateFail = as.Date(myDate)) %>% 
  mutate(newDateFail = as.Date("1969-07-29"))

  zipcode myDate     myDateTime          animal castDateFail newDateFail
    <int> <chr>      <dttm>              <chr>  <chr>        <chr>      
1   90210 2010-01-01 2023-06-01 10:06:35 cat    2010-01-01   1969-07-29
```

- Zipcode returns correctly as an *int*.
- myDateTime returns correctly as a *dttm*.
- **Why does myDate come back as *chr* ?**
- **Why does the cast of myDate fail?**
- **Why is newDateFail a *chr* instead of *date*?**

If I pipe to *show_query()* I get:

```
SELECT *, TRY_CAST('1969-07-29' AS DATE) AS "newDateFail"
FROM (
  SELECT *, TRY_CAST("myDate" AS DATE) AS "castDateFail"
  FROM "my_table"
) "q01"
```

If I *collect()* the data first, I am able to cast and mutate as expected, but I need to make date comparisons and join with another table before collecting.

I am running:

- R version 4.1.0
- dbplyr_2.3.2
- DBI_1.1.3
- sql Server 15

Comment: You are using a fairly antiquated ODBC driver: `"SQL Server"`, while the default on windows, is _ancient_. Upgrading to a more-modern ODBC (OS-level) driver will fix this, perhaps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16 to use the driver named `"ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server"`. (I'm still using 17 instead of 18 for a few reasons, it is also good.)

Comment: In case you already have it installed ... see `odbc::odbcListDrivers()` for something newer than what you showed above.

Comment: @r2evans suggestion of switching the driver worked.
I switched to Driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server", in my connection everything works as it should.
Thanks!